# SSRS how to use SnowFlake as a data source

Tags: snowflake-connector, ssrs-2017

I created a 64-bit ODBC User DSN for SnowFlake driver.  The SnowFlake data source is not showing in hte list of user or dsn when i'm trying to create a connection. Is snowflake driver allowed in MS Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 1):

Its supported, whether you create user DSN or System DSN, the DSN will reflect while you try to create new ODBC connection using that DSN.

Example, I created a user DSN in ODBC Data Sources 64 bit and using a ODBC tool such as Excel or Flyspeed to create connection using the DSN,its reflecting the user DSN.

[image]

Regards,
Sujan

Comment: I did create a 64-bit ODBC for Snowflake, but the issue was when i attempt to create a shared data source in VS 2017 it doesn't show up in the list